# Kubernetes custom health check

Tags: kubernetes

Do you think there is a way to create custom health check in kubernetes?

For example, using http get but if the content contains some string, then it's counted as failure.

Comment: There is an [open feature request on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55405) to support http response body matching. In the comments of the question, a workaround with an exec probe is proposed.

Comment: You can use an ExecAction, with curl and grep for exemple, to ensure the body match a given pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `exec` probe to create whichever logic you want. If your image contains curl, and your applications listens on 8080 port, you may insert something like

```yaml
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - exit "$(curl localhost:8080 | grep -c 'BAD_STRING')"
```

grep will return 0 if no "bad" strings are found, thus check will pass. Anything non-zero will result in probe failure.

You can use whichever script you find necessary, maybe you can put a healthcheck script inside your container and call it in exec section.

Relevant doc:

```
kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.readinessProbe.exec
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  apps/v1

RESOURCE: exec <Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     One and only one of the following should be specified. Exec specifies the
     action to take.

     ExecAction describes a "run in container" action.

FIELDS:
   command      <[]string>
     Command is the command line to execute inside the container, the working
     directory for the command is root ('/') in the container's filesystem. The
     command is simply exec'd, it is not run inside a shell, so traditional
     shell instructions ('|', etc) won't work. To use a shell, you need to
     explicitly call out to that shell. Exit status of 0 is treated as
     live/healthy and non-zero is unhealthy.
```

Comment: The downside is that we need to add a program (like `curl`) to our image that is not essential for the services' operation. Not only does that increase the image, it also increases the risk of making the container vulnerable to attacks. I know that for the time being, this is the only workaround we have, but the downside should be mentioned.